# Change API_URL after npm run build

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React.

I have created a sample project with the help of create-react-app. Everything is working fine.

I just want to know is there any possibility to change `API_URL` after `npm run build`. I have googled a lot but won't work.

Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: The question is quite vague. What and where is the `API_URL` used?
But yes, you can setup custom variables during builds for various environments.

Comment: please share your webpack config file

Comment: I think you will have a hard time changing it after the build, but you could give it a different `API_URL` with an [environment variable](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) during the build.

Comment: @Tholle yes your right i can set in environment variable  but my prob  is i have give build to multiple clients i cant set api url to each client. is there anyway to edit .env file after build.

Comment: The `.env` file is used during the build to give environment variables their values, and then it's not used anymore. If you have multiple clients with the same app, but with different environment variables, I think it's easiest to just make one separate build for each client instead.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue now. @user2695370 Did you find a solution for this problem? If so, share here.